# Live Agent pre-chat coming in with No visitor name or details

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

We are facing a weird issue, where some of our pre-chats in live agent come in with no name or details. It just opens the live agent visitor page and is not creating/finding the related contact.
However we do not face this issue with all the chats. We are unable to recreate this issue either as we are not sure how they are being initiated.

Has anyone faced a similar issue with Live Agent ?

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this happen if you use the `!LiveAgent_VisitorName` parameter - it comes up blank. I use this approach to set the Live Agent visitor name

```
function setName() {
 document.getElementById(“prechat_field”).value =
 document.getElementById(“firstname”).value + document.getElementById(“lastname”).value;
 return true;
}
```

This way when the user submits the form, the values they provided in the First Name and Last Name fields will set the Visitor name that appears to the agent.

Comment: Do you add that into the page where the chat is initiated Gaurav? As I am not sure how to edit it on the live agent side.